# putting password protection for each page

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I want to put to password protection for each page.  I am having around 20 pages. What are the code/ scripts to be incorporated . Whether each page to be designed with php code. Moro over, the user login_id, Password to be monitored /maintained in a database. In case, if CSV file is maintained, what would be the impact. Could any body help me in this case?

Comment: <?php require_once('authenticated.php'); //authenticated.php will not return unless the user is authenticated. 
//on line 2+ know that the user is authenticated :D

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file would be a fairly poor method of doing so, since then if the CSV file can be read then the passwords would become open to anybody who has the CSV file, and since people reuse passwords across multiple systems this could be potentially very bad.

the simplest way of password protecting data on a web server would be to use a .htpasswd / .htaccess method of user access control

Comment: O.K  I will put in Database of  PHP-MYSQL.  What about each page password protection?

Comment: A database is equally as bad as a simple csv since it is trivial to read in the event of intrusion, at a minimum you should be storing a salted and hashed password.. a slight amount more information is available at:P https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm